# R: Trying to read data from html page and parse table, but getting Error in htmlTreeParse()

Tags: r, xml, html-parsing

When I execute `htmlTreeParser()`, I am getting this error:

> Error in htmlTreeParse(webpage, error = function(...) { :
>       error in creating parser for
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       XML content does not seem to be XML: ''

Kindly someone help me to debug it.

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

theurl <- "http://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/"
webpage <- getURL(theurl)
webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)
pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is clearly stated in the error message. The url you provided does not point directly to an XML page.

Try this:

```
theurl <- "https://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank"
```

Comment: Didn't show an error when I just ran it (after correcting the lack of quotes.